# security check when serializing in stream char*

Tags: c++, security, stream, std

I have a logging macro that accepts a message and arguments, say:

```
int i = 5
LOG1("message", i);
```

This will log:

```
message, i = 5
```

To do this I rely on std::stream and operator <<.

Now if I do

```
char* a = "foo";
LOG1("message", a);
```

The result is going to be:

```
message, a = foo
```

The question is, is there a function that could check the value of char* is it safe to be used in stream `operator <<`, or what are the potential attacks that i should check for additionally to the obvious ... it being too long string.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, or what you mean by 'potential attacks'